# Is there any simple step to install Bolt CMS v5.x or Symfony 5 on a shared hosting via ssh?

Tags: symfony5, bolt-cms

I've tried to install Bolt 5 on A2 hosting (shared) as follow:

1. Connect via ssh to the shared hosting account
2. Move to public_html directory ( `cd public_html` )
3. Create the project as described via the [official documentation](https://docs.boltcms.io/5.0/installation/installation): `composer create-project bolt/project` my_project
4. Follow installation's instruction by setting up the database.
5. Move the project files to the right location: `cp -r ./myproject/* ./` and don't forget also the hidden files, including .htaccess
6. Load the webpage.
7. [Error message]: Bolt - Installation error
   If you can read this, you've (probably) installed Bolt in the wrong folder. It's recommended to install Bolt outside the so-called web root, ...
8. By following all the instruction displayed in the error message, no success.

Comment: can you set the webroot for your Hosting?

Comment: This is the last solution I should choose and the requirement is not to change server configuration but only app source code